# Largest factored composite Cunningham number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

A number of the form $b^{n}\pm 1$ is a [Cunningham number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_number), 
 with non-square integer $b>1$ and integer $n>2$. The [Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) and [Mersenne](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) numbers are Cunningham numbers. The [Cunningham Project](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/index.html) records various results.

For $n=2$, the largest [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) likely provides the answer, $(3756801695685 \times 2^{666669})^2 - 1$ in this case.

Is $F_{11} = 2^{2048} +1$ (617 digits) the largest completely factored Cunningham number? Or are there some special numbers of this type that are completely factored?

EDIT: I'm going to also rule out [Wagstaff primes](https://oeis.org/A000978).  $2^{13372531} +1$ is ([probably](http://www.primenumbers.net/prptop/prptop.php)) completely factored.

Comment: If you can factor Fermat number $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ for $n\leq 11$ then you can factor $2^{4096}-1=\prod_{n=1}^{11}F_n.$